# Do these all mean the same thing? ("Fue en ese momento en el que me enteré del atentado terrorista.")

Tags: gramática, pronombres, conjunciones, inglés

I appreciate all the answers I got from @Gustavson, @Diego, @cocteau and @Lambie. They were all helpful so I just picked one to mark as the anwer.

(I'm super-new so maybe it's silly for me to ask this until I understand more of the basics.)
SpanishDict.com has [this example sentence](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/momento):

> Fue en ese momento en el que me enteré del atentado terrorista.

It has this English translation:

> It was at that moment that I found out about the terrorist attack.

Would any of the following have the same meaning as the above? Would any of them be more common? Would any of them be more literal? If you have some kind of principles to help me understand which are right and which are wrong, I'd love to hear that too.

1. * Fue **en** ese momento **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (got this from google translate)
2. Fue **en** ese momento **en que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
3. Fue **en** ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
4. Fue ese momento **en el que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
5. Fue ese momento **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
6. Fue ese momento **en que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
7. Fue ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
8. * Eso fue el momento **en que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
9. * Ese fue el momento **en que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
10. Eso fue el momento **en el que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
11. Ese fue el momento **en el que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
12. Eso fue el momento **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
13. Ese fue el momento **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
14. * Fue entonces **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
15. Fue entonces **en el que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
16. Fue entonces **en que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
17. Fue entonces **que me** enteré del atentado terrorista.

The sentences with the "*" came from SpanishDict.com (but I changed the last clause), and some of them are from me trying to "mix and match" pieces of them together.

I was trying to understand why the original sentence is correct, and I ended up with this:
"en ese momento" = "en el [momento] que...", where "fue" is the "=." No idea whether that makes sense.

Comment: I certainly am not going down that entire list but this: Fue en ese momento en el que me enteré del atentado terrorista. would usually be: Fue en ese momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (*)Fue en ese momento [pausa] **que me** enteré del atentado terrorista (En ese momento recién se vino a enterar)
2. Fue en ese momento (en) que me enteré del atentado terrorista(Ese 'en' puede ir como no)

- 2.1. Fue en **ese** momento **que me** enteré del atentado terrorista(**Sin el segundo 'en'** significa que en ese momento recién se vino a enterar)
- 2.2. Fue en **ese** momento, **en el que me** enteré del atentado, que llamé a..(**Con el segundo 'en'** significa que la acción de llamar la hizo luego de enterarse)
- 2.3. Fue en **el** momento **que me** enteré del atentado, que llamé a..(Lo mismo que 2.2)

3. Fue en ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista(Perfecto, aunque cambiaría 'cuando' por 'que' o lo cambiaría de lugar, y cambiaría 'ese' por 'el')

- 3.1 Fue en ese momento **que** me enteré del atentado(Por fin se vino a enterar)
- 3.2 Fue en el momento **que** me enteré del atentado que hice tal cosa(Hizo eso después de que se enteró)
- 3.3 Fue **cuando** me enteré del atentado que hice tal cosa(Lo mismo que 3.2)

4. Fue **ese** momento **en el que me enteré** del atentado terrorista(Cambiaría 'ese' por 'el', lo cambiaría de lugar o agregaría 'en')

- 4.1. 'Fue justo **el** momento **en el que me** enteré del atentado'
- 4.2. 'Fue en **ese** preciso momento **que me** percaté del atentado'
- 4.3. '**Ese** fue el preciso momento **en que me** percaté del atentado'

5. <s>Fue ese momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista.</s>
   (Cambiaría 'Fue ese momento' por 'Desde el momento' o lo agregaría 'en')

- 5.1 **Desde el** momento **en que nos** enteramos del atentado, tomamos medidas...(Pero cambia el significado, se refiere al plan que se llevó a cabo luego del atentado y con 'nos' se refiere a quienes estuvieron a cargo)
- 5.2 Fue **en** ese momento **que me** enteré del atentado terrorista.

6. <s>Fue ese momento en que me enteré del atentado terrorista</s> (falta 'en', fue **en** ese momento)
7. <s>Fue ese momento cuando me enteré del atentado terrorista</s> (falta 'en', fue **en** ese momento)
8. <s>(*)**Eso** fue el momento en que me enteré del atentado terrorista</s> (Mal, 'eso' es el atentado)
9. (*) Ese fue **el** momento **en que me** enteré del atentado terrorista(Perfecto)
10. <s>**Eso** fue el momento en el que me enteré del atentado terrorista</s>(Mal, 'eso' es el atentado)
11. Ese fue el momento **en el que me** enteré del atentado terrorista(En Chile se escucha eso y me parece bien)
12. <s>Eso fue el momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista</s>(Mal, eso es el atentado)
13. <s>Ese fue el momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista</s>(Falta 'en', "Ese fue el momento **en** que me")
14. (*) Fue entonces cuando me enteré del atentado terrorista (En Chile se escucha eso y me parece bien)
15. Fue entonces <s>en el que</s> **que/cuando** me enteré/percaté/di cuenta del atentado terrorista(Mal)
16. **Solo** fue entonces <s>en que</s> **que me** di cuenta de que había ocurrido un/el atentado terrorista (Solo cuando pasó tal cosa se llegó realmente a enterar de lo sucedido, que se dio cuenta de lo que de verdad pasó, mal, sin 'en')
17. Fue entonces **que me** enteré del atentado terrorista (Perfecto)

Comment: Great answer @cocteau, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of emphasis works pretty much in Spanish as it does in English. The original sentence, without any emphasis, would be:

- Me enteré del atentado terrorista en ese momento. (I heard about the terrorist attack at that moment.)

(Note: In grammar, asterisks are used before sentences to indicate that they are ungrammatical and are thus used below.)

(A) We can produce a cleft sentence by taking any part of it, in this case the adverbial of time "en ese momento", to the front with the verb "ser" used impersonally (it + to be). Just as in English, we can join the clefted part of the sentence with the rest of it by means of "que" (that) or by means of the corresponding conjunction, in this case "cuando" (when):

- **Fue** en ese momento **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (It was at that moment **that** I heard about the terrorist attack.)
- **Fue** en ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (It was at that moment **when** I heard about the terrorist attack.)
- **Fue** en ese momento **en (el) que** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (Here "en (el) que" is equivalent to "when": It was at that moment when I heard about the terrorist attack.)

If the phrase "en el momento", which contains the noun "momento", is replaced with an adverb like "entonces" (then), only "que" and "cuando" will work because the relatives "en que" and "en el que" need to refer to a noun:

- **Fue** entonces **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (It was then that I heard about the terrorist attack.)
- **Fue** entonces **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (It was then when I heard about the terrorist attack.)

( * ) Fue entonces en (el) que me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*) It was then in which I heard about the terrorist attack.)

(B) We can also emphasize by using a demonstrative. The gender and number of the demonstrative has to agree with that of the noun being emphasized. Since "el momento" is masculine singular, we have to use "ese" (that one) or "este" (this one). Neuter "eso" is incorrect in this case because it means "that thing", and the moment is not a thing. In this case, the noun being emphasized is followed by a relative clause:

- **Ese fue** el momento **en (el) que/cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista. (That was the moment in which/when I heard about the terrorist attack.)

This is only acceptable in colloquial Spanish, as it is in English: Ese fue el momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista. (That was the moment (that) I heard about the terrorist attack)

The sentences that follow are INCORRECT because they don't follow the patterns above as they have been described:

( * ) Fue ese momento en (el) que me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*)It was that moment in which I heard about the terrorist attack.)

( * ) Fue ese momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*)It was that moment that I heard about the terrorist attack.)

( * ) Fue ese momento cuando me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*) It was that moment when I heard about the terrorist attack.)

( * ) Eso fue el momento en (el) que me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*)That thing was the moment in which I heard about the terrorist attack.)

( * ) Eso fue el momento que me enteré del atentado terrorista. ((*)That thing was the moment that I heard about the terrorist attack.)

Comment: Thanks @Gustavson!! Very cool.

Comment: Lol, I didn't know about the *. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, they are written alone, without parentheses, but here they automatically become bullet points if you don't write the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

**Fue en ese momento en el que me enteré del atentado terrorista.**

Estaba tratando de entender por qué la oración original es correcta, y terminé con esto: "en ese momento" = "en el [momento] que...", donde "fue" es el "=". No tengo idea de si eso tiene sentido.

> I was trying to understand why the original sentence is correct, and I
> ended up with this: "en ese momento" = "en el [momento] que...", where
> "fue" is the "=." No idea whether that makes sense.

---

Aunque muchas frases de las expuestas son incorrectas nº 6, nº7, nº 8, nº 10, nº 12... en general las demás son una repetición que solo expresan matices de la persona que habla.

En español como en otros idiomas, existen numerosas formas de decir lo mismo, y es necesario conocer un poco la gramática.

Lo más habitual en español de España es decir;

> Although many of the sentences exposed are incorrect No. 6, No. 7, No.
> 8, No. 10, No. 12... in general, the others are a repetition that only
> express nuances of the person speaking.
>
> In Spanish, as in other languages, there are numerous ways of saying
> the same thing, and it is necessary to know a bit of grammar.
>
> The most common in Spanish from Spain is to say;

- Fue en ese momento en el **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
- Fue en ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista.

En la primera oración la palabra "**que**" actúa como **pronombre relativo**, es decir,  *los pronombres relativos se utilizan para aludir a algo que fue mencionado previamente dentro de la oración*, y se usa preferentemente para evitar caer en la repetición. Este "**que**", como pronombre, puede ser sustituido normalmente por "**cual**".

> In the first sentence, the word "**que**" (that) acts as a relative
> pronoun, that is, **relative pronouns** *are used to refer to
> something that was previously mentioned in the sentence*, and is
> preferably used to avoid repetition. This "que" as a pronoun can
> normally be replaced by "**cual**" (which).

- Fue en ese momento en el **que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
- Fue en ese momento en el **cual** me enteré del atentado terrorista.

**Que**

https://dle.rae.es/que?m=form

En la segunda oración la palabra "**cuando**" actúa como adverbio relativo que introduce oraciones adjetivas de **significado temporal**.

"**En el tiempo en el que**" o "**en el momento en el que**". **En el que** o **en el cual**, **referido al tiempo**, con antecedente y más frecuentemente en relativas explicativas.

> In the second sentence the word "cuando" (when) acts as a relative
> adverb that introduces adjective sentences of **temporal meaning**.
>
> "In the time in "**en el que**" or in the moment in "**en el que**"
> (which). In "**en el que**" or in "**en el cual**" (which), referring
> to time, with antecedent and more frequently in relative explanatory.

- Fue en ese momento **cuando** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
- Fue en ese momento **en el que** me enteré del atentado terrorista.
- Fue en ese momento **en el cual** me enteré del atentado terrorista.

**Cuando**

https://dle.rae.es/cuando

Comment: Thanks @Diego, that helps a lot! I think I understand the "en el que" part pretty well now. Can you help me understand some of the nuances that can be expressed by changing this sentence slightly?

Comment: Con mucho gusto, aunque no es fácil. Principalmente remito a la diferencia entre "fue entonces" y "en ese momento". En estos casos concretamente  se refieren a la posición o consideración subjetiva que toma el hablante ante el suceso. - "fue entonces" alude al tiempo o momento del que se habla, alargando un poco más esa consideración en el espacio temporal de cuando ese algo ya sucedió. - "en ese momento" de alguna manera especifica el tiempo o ese momento puntual en el que sucede, ocurre o se realizó la cosa.

Comment: With pleasure, although it is not easy. Mainly I refer to the difference between "fue entonces" and "en ese momento". In these cases, they specifically refer to the position or subjective consideration that the speaker takes before the event. - "fue entonces" alludes to the time or moment of which it is spoken, extending a little more that consideration in the temporary space of when that something already happened. - "en ese momento" in some way specifies the time or that precise moment in which the thing happens, occurs or was done.